# The Bessel Equation? $x^2y′′+ xy'+ (x^2 - n^2) = 0$ has a regular singularity at $x$ equals to?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me to answer:
 The Bessel Equation? $x^2y′′+ xy'+ (x^2 - n^2) = 0$ has a regular singularity at $x$ equals to ?

Comment: Hi i think you have a typo in Equation there should a $y$ in the last term

Answer (score 1):

There is always a singularity at $x=0$ for Bessel Equation

If you have $P(x)y''+Q(x)y'+R(x)y=0$ then it has a singularity when $\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$ and $\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}$ are not defined here that is only when when $x=0$